# Why does the GDB 'step' command skip struct declarations?

Tags: gdb

```
int main(void)
{
    char A[] ='hi';
    struct dayInfo day;
    int x = 1;
}
```

So in gdb I did

```
gdb> breakpoint main
gdb> run
```

**output:**

```
Breakpoint 1 , main()  line 1

char A[]= 'hi';

gdb>  step
```

**output:**

```
int x = 1;   line 3
```

Q: Just started learning `GDB` and I don't understand why 'step' command skips to

```
int x = 1;   line 3.
```

Why is it not `struct dayInfo day;`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a local variable is declared no code is executed. The compiler takes the declaration into account by making a bigger stack frame, so effectively the variable declaration was performed when the function was entered. There's no code where gdb could stop between lines 1 and 3, so it continues to the next line.

Comment: Hi~ could you please explain little bit more?